# How to Size PDF in swift

Tags: swift, pdf, uigraphicscontext

There are various ways to create PDF in swift, but is there any possible to resize the PDF document.

`UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` has `bounds` property but that defines the size of the PDF but the UIView is rendered in the context with original size.

This is what I have used so far

```
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds , nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
  guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    aView.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a minute, but I believe the PDF is created based on the size of the content you're putting into it. I worked with images, where I could control the size. Not sure if you're working with text or other media. Hope it helps. 
¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm working with the multiple images in a complex view hierarchy so I cannot easily resize the view. Also I tried to render the view into a UIImage but that greatly degrades the quality of the images the PDF